# I need to generate a formula-wiped report from an excel tool I made, and wiped charts (probably converted to images). Having issues with the charts

Tags: excel, vba

So I know this is similar to some other questions but I was unable to find what I needed. The TLDR is I am copying some sheets from one workbook to a completely new workbook that the macro generates. I need all references to the old workbook wiped but the numbers saved. But, I also need the plots saved, and I'm assuming they need to be converted to images - that's where I'm having issues.

I need to generate a data-wiped report from an excel tool I made, with blank values, and wiped charts (probably converted to images). This is what I have so far: I can take my excel tool results, and use a button driven macro I made that exports a report page (and a cooresponding "raw data" page so results could be recreated later if needed) to a folder in my drive, it basically just "saves as" just those two sheets. It then wipes the values in all cells so that the links I have that make up the "report" page are not lingering and tied to anything - I can email someone those two sheets and they can see my results without needing to see my massive excel tool. Also means I don't have to store like 100 versions of this clunky excel tool. But, the plots keep coming in linked to the original and I cannot for the life of me find anything on how to wipe them - short of exporting them as an image completely separately, which I don't want to have to do.

While I'm at it, it sure would be nice if I could export those two tabs together instead of what it does now, which is generate two separate excel documents, one titled "Report" and one titled "Raw_Data".

Anyone have any ideas how I could go about basically taking the worksheets I created, and in the same macro, having it delete the chart that was there, and replace it with an image of the chart?

I would love to elaborate further, please let me know if I can help you understand my issue. Thanks!

I tried this code, with my 3 notes about replacing those filepaths you'd expect because the project is kind of proprietary and I don't want to release that path. My main worksheet title is "Speed to Start 2.0" and :

```vb
Sub ExportWorksheets()

    Dim worksheet_list As Variant, worksheet_name As Variant
    Dim new_workbook As Workbook
    Dim saved_folder As String
    
    worksheet_list = Array("Report", "Raw_Data")
    '// makes sure you close the path with a back slash
    saved_folder = "(I'm redacting this filepath for proprietary reasons)\\"
    
    For Each worksheet_name In worksheet_list
    
        On Error Resume Next
        ' Opens a new Excel workbook
        Set new_workbook = Workbooks.Add
        
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(worksheet_name).Copy new_workbook.Worksheets(1)
        
        new_workbook.SaveAs saved_folder & worksheet_name & ".xlsx", 51
        

        
'        new_workbook.Close False
        
    Next worksheet_name
    
'This is the point where it kept messing up, originally.

Dim wbBook1 As Workbook
Dim wbBook2 As Workbook
Dim wbBook3 As Workbook

Set wbBook1 = ThisWorkbook
Set wbBook2 = Workbooks.Open("(I'm redacting this filepath for proprietary reasons but it's the filepath to the excel report that gets generated)")
Set wbBook3 = Workbooks.Open("(I'm redacting this filepath for proprietary reasons but it's the filepath to the excel report that gets generated)")

Dim wsSheet1 As Worksheet
Dim wsSheet2 As Worksheet
Dim wsSheet3 As Worksheet

Set wsSheet2 = wbBook2.Worksheets("Report")
Set wsSheet3 = wbBook3.Worksheets("Raw_Data")
    
   With wsSheet2.UsedRange
        .Copy
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
        Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With

    With wsSheet3.UsedRange
        .Copy
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
        Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With

'This is the point where, presumably, I would be able to cut and paste all charts on the worksheets 
'(wbBook2&3, first page of each) and replace them with images. 
'There are only 2... but idk how to select them.

    wbBook2.Save
    wbBook3.Save

    MsgBox "Export complete.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array("Report", "Raw_Data")).Copy` will create a new workbook with those two sheets.  The new workbook will be the activeworkbook after it's created.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```vb
Sub ExportWorksheets()

    Dim worksheet_list As Variant, worksheet_name As Variant
    Dim new_workbook As Workbook
    Dim saved_folder As String, t As Long, l As Long, co As ChartObject
    
    saved_folder = "(I'm redacting this filepath for proprietary reasons)\\"
    worksheet_list = Array("Report", "Raw_Data")
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(worksheet_list).Copy  'make a copy
    Set new_workbook = ActiveWorkbook             'new workbook with copies
    
    For Each worksheet_name In worksheet_list
        With new_workbook.Worksheets(worksheet_name)
            .UsedRange.Value = .UsedRange.Value 'replace any formulas
            For Each co In .ChartObjects
                t = co.Top
                l = co.Left
                co.Cut
                .Pictures.Paste
                With .Shapes(.Shapes.Count)
                    .Top = t
                    .Left = l
                End With
            Next co
        End With
    Next worksheet_name

    new_workbook.SaveAs saved_folder & "output_" & _
         Format(Date, "yyyy_mm_dd") & ".xlsx", 51
  
    MsgBox "Export complete.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

As an alternative to converting the charts to images, you could try embedding the data:

```vb
    '...
    For Each co In .ChartObjects
        ChartFixValues co.Chart
    Next co
    '...
```

Fix chart values:

```
Sub ChartFixValues(cht As Chart)
    Dim ser As Series
    For Each ser In cht.FullSeriesCollection
        ser.Name = ser.Name
        ser.Values = ser.Values
        ser.XValues = ser.XValues
    Next ser
End Sub
```

Comment: If this answer was useful, please flag as "accepted", to help anyone coming along later with a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI that worked absolutely fantastic! The few edits I made were to add the hours/minutes/seconds to the filename so I don't overwrite anything ever. That change was:

```
new_workbook.SaveAs saved_folder & "Speed_to_Start_Results_" & _
     Format(Date, "yyyy_mm_dd") & "_" & Format(Time, "hhmmss") & ".xlsx", 51
```

Thank you SO much for helping me figure that out Tim! The charts are perfectly wiped and converted to images in the copied report page.